# Bootstrap Toggle button Error-"Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '/navbarSupportedContent' is not a valid selector."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, bootstrap-4

I use bootstrap to make a Navbar and it works totally fine but when i want to see it in the mobile screen to check responsiveness of the site, the toggle button is not functioning and it shows error like-
"bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '/navbarSupportedContent' is not a valid selector."

How to Fix This?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Thank You Sir! But the problem is now fixed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, Your **Console** is your bestfriend. Try to look at the console what error it throws at you, in this case we have error **'/navbarSupportedContent' is not a valid selector.**, that means there are some error lies in "navbarSupportedContent".
Go to your code-
*data-bs-target="/navbarSupportedContent"*

**Replace that "/" with a "#"**.

I hope this will solve Your problem!

Answer (score 1):

That is because you might using "/" instead of "#" in your code.
[image: data-bs-target]

Use in toggle button **`data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"`** in your Bootstrap Navbar.